# Grails --- loader constraint violation

Tags: grails, geb

In one of my application i have to use geb with grails. i installed geb plugin and added dependency selenium standalone jar.

Now the problem is while i cleaning or compiling i got the error like following

Interactive mode exited with error: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method `"org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.getXMLReader()Lorg/xml/sax/XMLReader;"` the class loader `(instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader)` of the current class, `org/apache/xerces/jaxp/SAXParserImpl,` and its superclass loader (`instance of <bootloader>`), have different Class objects for the type `org/xml/sax/XMLReader` used in the signature (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: Run `grails dependency-report` and search for conflicts there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the transitive dependency of Selenium to `xml-apis` like this in your `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
dependencies {
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        exclude "xml-apis"
    }
    test "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    test "org.codehaus.geb:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"
}
```

See [this example project](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy) for more details.